# facebook get shared count not-deleted and not-private

Tags: facebook-fql, facebook-opengraph, developer-tools

Is possible to get share count from url exclude "deleted shared post" and private post

"SELECT share_count FROM link_stat WHERE url = A" return all shared action

https://api.facebook.com/restserver.php?method=links.getStats&urls=http://example.com/&format=json same data

Answer (score 0):

Temporary is not possible

> **Stephen Doyle**: What you've described is the intended operation of that endpoint at present - the number includes all shares regardless
>   of whether those shares are currently visible to the user making the
>   API call

details: https://developers.facebook.com/x/bugs/1429537640626458/